# How can I (or should I) test that observation A tends to be greater than observation B for each subject?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I measured 2 sediment parameters in multiple lakes.  The organic matter content at the sediment/water interface `surfOM` and the mean organic matter content of the whole core `meanOM`.

```
surfOM <- c(34.4600, 42.1700, 48.6700, 18.4711, 19.5300, 18.4238, 20.5601, 28.2800, 19.1739)
meanOM <- c(31.23571, 37.57117, 43.47832, 18.47110, 17.18266, 17.42377, 19.96015, 25.09943, 19.37392)
```

The two measures are correlated `> cor(surfOM, meanOM) [1] 0.9967266` and `surfOM` is generally greater than `meanOM`:

```
 > surfOM - meanOM
[1]  3.22429  4.59883  5.19168  0.00000  2.34734  1.00003  0.59995  3.18057
[9] -0.20002
```

When reporting the results I say:

> "The surface percent organic matter and the mean percent organic matter of the same core were highly correlated with slightly greater surface percent organic matter in most lakes."

I did not initially feel like the difference needed a statistical test because it just is what it is but both reviewers asked for a test showing that surfOM tends to be greater than meanOM in a lake.

My initial thought was to calculate the confidence interval of `surfOM - meanOM` and show that it does not contain 0 but I am not sure if this is the most appropriate approach.

Questions:

- Does the difference between the two variables need a statistical test?
- What is an appropriate way of testing this difference?

(Note: this is just a subset of the data.  The complete dataset has 23 lakes)

Comment: (+1) It's a good question.  Concerning how to report results: first, it needs a comma before "with" to be understood correctly.  Second, it is better to be quantitative instead of using the qualitative "slightly," although "highly correlated" is ok.  You might instead write, "The surface % o.m. is highly correlated with the mean % o.m. in each core and exceeds it on average by 3.2%" (or whatever the mean difference is).

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your feedback on the results, that is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a paired t-test.

In R, `t.test(surfOM,meanOM,paired=TRUE)`

That will give you a p-value and a confidence interval for the mean of the differences. These only really makes sense if the lakes are a sample of a larger population of lakes, not if you have data on all the lakes in your population (e.g. all the lakes in some geographical area, or all the lakes of a certain type of interest).

Comment: +1 One *never* has complete information about sediment characteristics: these data are measurements of very small portions of the total sediments in each lake.  Therefore these data make perfect sense when either (a) inference is about this set of lakes and/or (b) inference is about all lakes and these form a representative sample.

Answer (score 3):

When I hear the statement "A tends to be greater than B" it sounds like A is greater than B a bunch of the time, say, more than 50% of the time.  This can happen when $\mu_{A}$ is greater than $\mu_{B}$, but it can also happen that $\mu_{A}$ is greater than $\mu_{B}$... yet $P(A > B) < 0.50$.

(For a concrete example of what I'm getting at, let B be identically 1/2, and let A put probability $1 - p$ on zero with its remaining probability $p$ on some integer $n \geq 1$.  We can make $P(A > B)$ as small as we like by letting $p \to 0$, yet we can make $\mu_{A}$ as big as we like by letting $n \to \infty$.)

On top of all this, it looks like your "B" is itself a "mean", which complicates the language.

So, my first thought is to try to figure out whether you'd be more interested in $\mu_{A} > \mu_{B}$ or if you'd rather be more interested in $P(A > B) > 0.50$.  If you're interested in the means then the t-test should be just fine.

If you're more interested in $P(X > Y)$, you might consider the [Sign Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test).  It's a nonparametric test, it's light on assumptions, and you don't need to be so concerned about outliers. If you could additionally say that the distribution of the differences of organic matter was symmetric, you could do one better and go for the [Wilcoxon Signed Rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test).

Anyway, suppose you can say nothing more about the distributions, and suppose they are appropriate for the Sign Test.  The data given above had 8 out of 9 pairs with A greater than B. For these data, in R, you would do

```
binom.test(8, 9, alt = "greater")
```

The output would give a p-value and a 95% one-sided Clopper-Pearson confidence interval (which generally is conservative).

Comment: Ha! double-checking the data it looks like entry 4 is a tie!  That's one of the wrinkles of the Sign Test.  There are several ways to address that, and here's a paper that talks about some of them: http://www.jstor.org/pss/2683818.  But given the context, is that truly a tie...?

Comment: Kerns - thanks for your answer.  I am most interested in $P(A > B)>0.50$ so I will look into the Sign Test.  It is a true tie.  `surfOM` is the y-intercept of a linear model of %OM by depth (i.e., the %OM at depth = 0) in a few cases the slope of the model was not different from 0 so I used the `meanOM` as `surfOM`.

Comment: I see.  Well, the quick and dirty approach is to throw away the ties.  This has advantages and disadvantages (see the paper).  And, it might not be appropriate for your study;  you'd have to decide (and defend) in the context of the bigger picture of your research question.  For the given data, the conclusion doesn't change whether you keep them or not (but the interval estimates do, of course).

Comment: Also: bear in mind that nowhere is it chiseled in stone that we must throw away every slope estimate which doesn't have a p-value vanishingly small (it's typed on paper in lots of places, though).  You may judge it worthwhile to keep the slopes -- at least temporarily -- to investigate a different question which may be important.  On the face of it, I'd rather preserve the information in the slope estimates than throw the ties completely away.  Bottom line: we are searching for the *truth*, and the path leading there isn't always paved in steel with road signs pointing everywhere.